# GridView problems with touchlisteners

Tags: android, gridview, touch-event

I'm trying to create a custom `GridView` but i'm having troubles with the touch listeners.

What i want to do:

- Create a `GridView` with custom `Views`.
- Longpress on an item so it becomes 'editable'.
- Drag the view horizontal or vertical to move it's position in the `GridView`.

Here's where i'm having trouble:
I'm implementing `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` for the longpress functions, because for some reason using the `gridview.setOnItemLongClickListener()` isn't working when overriding the `onTouchEvent()` of the `GridView` itself (Which i need for the dragging part). So everything is fine at this point. Now i only need to know when the longpress is finished. So i though: "Well this shouldn't be hard." I couldn't have be more wrong. I've fiddled around for quite some time with this and it looks like using different touch events isn't helping me :/
When stepping through the `onTouchEvent()` i noticed that only 1 action is given: `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`. So what am i doing wrong? i need the `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`...

Comment: Did you ever finish this? Been looking for something like this, Are you able to share the custom grid view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the culprit:

i was doing something like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Give everything to the gesture detector
    boolean retValue = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            onMove();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            onUp();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            onCancel();
            break;
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

i think `retValue` was always returning false so no other events were triggered.
this fixed the issue:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // Give everything to the gesture detector
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE :
            onMove();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
            onUp();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            onCancel();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```